# How can I get Gunicorn to stop printing so many repeated startup messages?

Tags: gunicorn

I'm running gunicorn with:

```
gunicorn --workers 1 \
>   --bind=localhost:4242 \
>   --access-logfile="${ACCESS_LOG}" \
>   --error-logfile="${ERROR_LOG}" \
>   --log-level=INFO \
>   my_app.noisy_gunicorn
```

`my_app.noisy_gunicorn` is just a two line Python script:

```
import flask

application = flask.Flask(__name__)
```

Gunicorn starts up with:

```
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4242 (54188)
: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
[2023-09-27 15:52:17 -0400] [54189] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54189
...
```

Is there any way to make it not be so verbose about starting up 1 worker? It seems like it's the `--error-logfile` and/or `--access-logfile` options that are triggering this nonsense, but I want to keep my logs around!